# Strace daemon process started using service

Tags: system-calls, systemd, strace

Strace can be used for tracing process by passing command for the process as below

`strace -f -tt -o strace.log -D <SOME_COMMAND>`

But below command fails to trace the syscalls of started daemon process

`strace -f -tt -o strace.log -D service nginx start`

In this case the strace just traces syscall for `/usr/sbin/service` and terminates. It does not trace syscalls on `nginx` process which is started as result of `service nginx start`

How do a I trace the process started by `/usr/sbin/service`? Specifically looking for solution with daemon process only!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of running the `nginx` from service. Run `service nginx stop` and then run

```
strace nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

this will make sure that you get the trace of the process. The `-g "daemon off;"` will make sure the nginx is not run as a daemon process, else again the strace would end

Service command is just activating a process and if you want to `strace` it the best is to launch the process directly.

In case you are still interested in debugging the process started using the service command. Then do below

```
service nginx start
ps aux | grep nginx
```

Capture the `pid` from the nginx process and then attach to it using

```
strace -p <pid>
```

**Forking Processes**

To trace processes which fork, you need to use the `-f` flag

```
strace -f nginx
```

**Service tracing**

When you call `service start nginx`, assuming the system uses `systemd`, the call gets translated to `systemctl start nginx`. Now if you look at the source code of `systemd`

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/cf45dd36282368d5cdf757cac2cf1fc2b562dab2/src/systemctl/systemctl.c#L3100

```
r = sd_bus_call_method_async(
    bus,
    NULL,
    "org.freedesktop.systemd1",
    "/org/freedesktop/systemd1",
    "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager",
    "Subscribe",
    NULL, NULL,
    NULL);
```

It doesn't spawn/fork the process. It sends the message to the systemd service which then starts `nginx` process.

So in short, **NO** you can't strace through your `service nginx start` command.

Comment: I am specifically looking for solution with daemon on! Otherwise its straight forward!

Comment: I already have used -f. The reason I am looking for answer is I could then trace `service XYZ start` correctly!

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain the reason for the downvote and what is wrong with the answer

Comment: The answer circumvents the problem, and is therefore inapplicable to situations in which the problem cannot be circumvented.

Answer (score 4):

Change the ExecStart property of the service to include "strace". For example (tested on Debian Buster):

```
# grep ExecStart /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
# cd /etc/systemd/system/
# mkdir nginx.service.d
# cat > nginx.service.d/strace.conf <<-EOD
    [Service]
    ExecStart=
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/strace -f -tt -o /tmp/strace.log -D /usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
EOD
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart nginx.service
```